# TOP clause in SQL server returns more records than specified

Tags: sql-server

**TOP** clause in SQL server(I tried this in w3schools.com website) gives more records than specified when used with **order by** clause. This is the query I used:

```
 select TOP 1 * from orders left join customers on 
 orders.customerID=customers.customerID order by EmployeeID desc
```

Please visit this link for my result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg7sV.jpg

Instead, this query returns 6 records. Is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: can you please share a repro for us to test

Comment: Can you show us some data to prove this? Or as @TheGameiswar suggested, share a reproduction of this occurrence? Otherwise we're all shooting in the dark

Comment: Shooting in the dark at noises. `TOP 1` doesn't behave like this. You'll have to post a script that actually reproduces this behaviour, because it's the opposite of what anyone else has seen. Post the table scripts the data and the *actual* query you tried. Most likely it wasn't what you posted here

Comment: Just because this happens on the w3schools site does NOT mean it will happen in sql server. The query you posted will never return more than 1 row in sql server.

Comment: ttps://i.stack.imgur.com/xg7sV.jpg

Comment: Like everyone here is writing, please try it on a real sql server instance. Something is wrong in the site. Please try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/516c3b/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the **ENTIRE** screen. And obviously there is something terribly wrong with their site.

[image]

Comment: They give this comment for almost every query:
 select * from orders 
even for this simple query we get that message.

Comment: Yes, There is obviously something wrong with their website. I agree with you. When I try the below query in MYSQL DB in w3schools it works perfectly with LIMIT clause. 

select * from Customers left join Orders on Orders.CustomerID=Customers.customerID order by EmployeeID desc LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN part throws you off. Try something like this instead:

```
select TOP 1 * from orders a
outer apply (select top 1 * from customers where customerID = a.customerID) b
order by a.EmployeeID desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to order the query by name, address, by the order date or whatever that doesn't REPEAT like the EmployeeID. Souns like a very very dumb solution but it worked for me in an Access database with DESC counts.

Looks like if in orders the values repeat the sql returns more than needed... i really don't know why but it worked for me!

Try it!